# Spectral Lint whole project (all YAML/JSON files) in IntelliJ

Tags: json, openapi, intellij-14, spectral, stoplight

I am working on spectral linting tool to linting the API (YAML/JSON). I want to lint all the files (YAML/JSON) which are available in the project using IntelliJ. Please share the details to setup and process if anyone worked on Spectral Linting toll.

Can anyone please share the setup details and process it?